# C# view data in form linked with foreign key

Tags: c#, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have a local database (SQL) with two tables Contact and Address. The Contact table contains 5 address fields (Address1, Address2,...) that are foreign keys linked to the primary key of the Address table. What ik want to do is when I select (for instance using a combobox) a contacts name, view all addresses linked to the contact. I'm a complete noob in C# programming and have no idee to make the above happen. Can anyone show me how I can view the addresses by selecting the contacts name?

EDIT (after trying some coding):
Ok, this is how far I get. I have my two forms. FORM 1 has a datagridview, viewing a button, firstname and lastname. Entering firstname and lastname in textBox1 and textBox2 and pressing button1 results in a list of records that match firstname OR lastname.
Clicking the button in column 0 shows the contactsheet. I've tried to pass firstname and lastname to textboxes tboFNAME and tboLNAME, but nothing appears in these textboxes.

In the next stage I would like to pass the address ID's (foreign keys) to the contactsheet and subsequently load the linked data in the corresponding textboxes.

FORM 1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\xxx\xxx\xxx.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\xxx\xxx\xxx.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        dataGridView1.Visible = true;
        int varCount;
        varCount = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 1 ; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
        {
            if (!dataGridView1.Rows[i].IsNewRow)
            {

                if (dataGridView1[3, i].Value.ToString() == textBox1.Text
                    || dataGridView1[5, i].Value.ToString() == textBox2.Text
                    )
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;

                    varCount += 1;
                    Console.WriteLine(varCount);
                    int RHeight = dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height;
                    int gridHeight = (varCount * RHeight) + RHeight;
                    dataGridView1.Height = gridHeight;
                 }

                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'sAFIREDBDataSet1.contactdata' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.contactdataTableAdapter1.Fill(this.sAFIREDBDataSet1.contactdata);
        this.contactdataTableAdapter.Fill(this.sAFIREDBDataSet.contactdata);
        }
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
        String fnameRef = (String)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value;
        String lnameRef = (String)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value;
        if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
        e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            Contactsheet myForm = new Contactsheet();
            myForm.getFNAME = fnameRef;
            myForm.getLNAME = lnameRef;
            myForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

FORM 2 (Contactsheet)

```
public partial class Contactsheet : Form
{
    public Contactsheet()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string getFNAME;
    public string getLNAME;
    private void Contactsheet_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tboFNAME.Text = getFNAME;
        tboLNAME.Text = getLNAME;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is too broad, please specify your problem and show some code. Start step by step, what is the first thing which you can not do ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must connect to your SQL db as you probably know. 
I think that the simplest way will be to use Entity Framework (version 5 or 6).
Create new edmx file, new connection to your database and import your tables.

Try to write some code. May be you figured it out. If not then ask more accurate question with examples of your tries:)